# Append text to the last line of a file in unix

Tags: unix, sed, append

I want to append a colon character (:) at the end of the last line of a text file (not in a new line).

- My file already has a \n character at the end so `printf ":" >> file` puts the colon in a new line.
- Using `sed '$s/$/:/' file > newfile` works, but my file is ~100 MB so piping the whole thing just to add a single character seems unattractive.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled because if `sed '$s/$/:/' file` works, it implies that you do not have a newline character at the end of `file`. What you present is however the best solution.

Comment: @kvantour sed never see \n at the end of line.

Comment: @ctac_ I agree with you except for the last line of a file. For instance,  POSIX sed will not process the last line if it doesn't end with a `newline` character while GNU sed does. This has as a consequence that GNU sed will add the `:` character in a new line while The other one on the end of the file. At least this is what my testcase gives when I compare GNU with SUNWcs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with `dd` and `notrunc` (tested on Linux 4.12):

```
printf ":" | dd of=file conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=$(( $(stat -c "%s" file) - 1))
```

Comment: I'll need to deploy this script to various UNIX and Solaris systems so I'll have to test if this works on all of them first. Thanks a lot, Thor. :)

Comment: @Yiorgos: `notrunc` is specified by POSIX, so it should be straightforward.  To improve your success-rate of useful answers, you should probably read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers