# Adding a dot in the last line of a file

Tags: bash, awk

I want to add a dot (full stop) in the last line (last character) of the file

**The file:**

```
AAAAAA              21,28,22-23,35,24-27,29-30,37,31-34,36,54,38-45,47,46,48-53,
AAAAAA              71,55-70,72-78,80,79,81-93,96,94-95,97-98,100,99,101-103,
AAAAAA              122,104-114,118,115-117,119-121,123-124,140,125-130,148,
AAAAAA              1649-1650,1652-1667,1669-1853
```

**Desired output**

```
AAAAAA              21,28,22-23,35,24-27,29-30,37,31-34,36,54,38-45,47,46,48-53,
AAAAAA              71,55-70,72-78,80,79,81-93,96,94-95,97-98,100,99,101-103,
AAAAAA              122,104-114,118,115-117,119-121,123-124,140,125-130,148,
AAAAAA              1649-1650,1652-1667,1669-1853**.**
```

**My code:**

```
sed '$d' file > tmp1
tail -1 file > tmp2
sed -i 's/$/./' tmp2

cat tmp1 tmp2 > output
```

I got the desired output with the code above.
Is there a more efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: This is sort of related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249773/append-text-to-the-last-line-of-a-file-in-unix#comment87518563_50249773

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tell sed to only change the last line.

```
sed '$s/$/./'
```

Comment: Ignacio, Great, tks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `echo` , this will work only if your last line doesn't already contains a carriage return

```
echo -n "." >> file
```

Comment: This will not work if the file already has a terminating newline character on the last line (which is very likely).

Comment: I had considered this, but realized that it would break if the last line ended with a NL.